# URL Re-Writing ASP.NET ( UrlRewriter.net )

Tags: asp.net, urlrewriter.net

Ok we have the following re-written URL using UrlRewriter.net

```
/category/games/21
```

using the following expression.

```
<rewrite url="~/Category/(.+)/(.+)" to="~/category.aspx?CatId=$2" />
```

however google can attach the following,

```
/category/games/21?gclid=clickIdHere
```

this would need to be re-written to,

```
/category.aspc?CatId=21&gclid=clickIdHere
```

Can anyone help suggest an expression that will work with the above?

I suppose somthing like...

```
<rewrite url="~/Category/(.+)/(.+)?gclid=(.+)" to="~/category.aspx?
CatId=$2&gclid=$3" />
```

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be like

```
<add name="category" virtualUrl="^~/Category.aspx/(.*)/(.*)" destinationUrl="~/Category.aspx?CatID=$1&amp;gclid=$2" ignoreCase="true" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" />
```

Comment: I have a different question though, how can i completely remove it? I mean the gclid. I have the similar situation but i do not wont the gclid to appear at all.